# Sparkstreaming not consistently picking files from streaming directory for processing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming for text files. I have feeder program which moves files to spark streaming directory.

while Spark processing particular file at the same time if feeders puts another file into streaming directory, sometimes spark does not pick file for processing.

we are using sparking streaming directory as NFS mounted shared drive so that spark slaves using mesos can also access it.

below is simple code

```
  final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf(); 

  final JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = 
                new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, 
                    new Duration(2000)); 

 JavaDStream<String> dstreamRdd = javaStreamingContext.textFileStream("/mnt/streamDir");
```

there is processing on this rdd later..

Any idea why Sparking streaming missing files in streaming directory once its moved from feeder?

Comment: Did you check that the same code is working with HDFS for example?

Comment: No I did not checked on HDFS as our environment just have NFS and MapR.